# Drupal REST in IOS failed with 403 forbidden access but success in browser

Tags: ionic-framework, drupal

My app can interact with Drupal API in the browser but not in the simulator and device. (Currently testing in iOS).

How can I fix it?
Everything is working fine in the browser but in the simulator/device, I get 403 forbidden access.

**The problem that might cause it**

I think the issue is with cookies? In Drupal, I have **ini_set(‘session.cookie_samesite’, ‘none’);** and it works. If I removed that, I get 403 forbidden access in the browser, simulator & device.
If I add that, it works on the browser but not in simulator/device.

**How can I fix this?**

Can I use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ instead of angular http service? Does it support withCredentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a different authentication method if you want to access the site from different devices. By default, Drupal has "Samesite" to "Strict" I think. Setting the samesite to "None" means that other domains or devices can access the same cookies from your website.